# Ender 5 Pro - Breaking sound when z axis moves down (away from hotend)

Tags: z-axis, bltouch, motor, creality-ender-5

I got this printer literally yesterday, at first it was fine but after a few test XYZ cube prints it started making a breaking noise when the Z axis moves down! Please see the video!

I'm about to return it, but thought maybe I have misconfigured something!

I'm not 100 % sure where exactly the noise is coming from, the motor itself or the connection of the pole with the bed!

Note this only happens when the z axis is moving down, the other way around it is fine!

Also this might be helpful: **it stops making the noise** when it is 2/3 of the way down then it becomes smooth!

Comment: Have you looked into binding? You could check the linear guides and lead screw if the printer is correctly assembled, or that those parts aren't bent.

Comment: I did but couldn't find anything related to this model, tried to loosen the screws on the round cylinder but no difference! Maybe I'm doing it wrong!